# Not all code return a value for lists

Tags: c#, class, object, int

I dont know what the error is, im trying to retrieve values from a list and add them, i dont know what is happening in the code, the error occurs at ReturnAttacks and AttackLoop.

```
public class test{
    public static List<int> attacks = new List<int>();
    public static void AddAttack(int attack){
        attacks.Add (attack);

    }

    public static int ReturnAttacks(){
        int numofattacks = attacks.Count;
        int returnval = 10;
        if (numofattacks > 5) {
            return returnval;
        }
        AttackLoop();
    }
    public static int AttackLoop(){
        foreach (int attack in attacks) {
            return attack;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        AddAttack(1);
        AddAttack(2);
        AddAttack(3);
        AddAttack(4);
        AddAttack(5);
        AddAttack(6);
        int selection = ReturnAttacks();

    }

}
```

Comment: So what does `AttackLoop` return if there are no attacks in `attacks`? Hint: It doesn't. Fix that. Same for `ReturnAttacks`.

Comment: Are you trying to return an `IEnumerable` if `int` in your `AttackLoop` method?

Comment: Please explain what is your expected result value.

Comment: One of your issues is that you're not returning anything in `ReturnAttacks()` if `numofattacks` is <= 5, the other is that `AttackLoop` doesn't return anything if `attacks` is empty

Comment: also @RichardDing can you explain why you are calling / trying to return data in a foreach loop.. perhaps you should look at or refactor the code you use `break;` also can you better explain what the program is supposed to do.. you appear to be calling the same method numerous times passing in int values.. perhaps you can have a single method call that iterates and Calls ReturnAttacks using a single method call within a for loop etc...

Answer (score 1):

In the AttackLoops () function, the function returns the value of attack in the first iteration of the loop, and that is it. Try returning the value outside the loop, or go for a generator function.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"***im trying to retrieve values from a list and add them***"

In that case,

```
 List<int> Attacks  = new List<int>();

        Attacks.Add(1);
        Attacks.Add(2);
        Attacks.Add(3);
        Attacks.Add(4);
        Attacks.Add(5);
        Attacks.Add(6);

        int SumOfInts = 0;
        foreach (int i in Attacks)
            SumOfInts += i;

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of Attacks {0}", SumOfInts);

        Console.Read();
```

Unless the problem requires your to write a class with a list and functions to add items to the list,retrieve and sum the items of the list.

```
public class test{
    public static List<int> attacks = new List<int>();

    public static void AddAttack(int attack){
        attacks.Add (attack);
    }

    public static int ReturnAttacks(){
        int sumOfAttacks = 0;
        foreach(int attack in attacks)
            sumOfAttacks += attack;

        return sumofAttacks;  
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        AddAttack(1);
        AddAttack(2);
        AddAttack(3);
        AddAttack(4);
        AddAttack(5);
        AddAttack(6);

        int selection = ReturnAttacks();

        Console.WriteLine(selection);
   }
}
```